# grunt-init templatename create nothing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grunt-init

I'm using grunt-init to make a new solution file for c# to be used by omnisharp.

I have already installed grunt-init using:

npm install -g grunt-init

and the installantion was successful. The problem is that, every time I run grunt-init csharpsolution on top of a directory, there is no output coming out of the shell. And, there is no file at all created. I have git-cloned ./grunt-init/csharpsolution already.

Is there something I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved after I installed nodejs using the instruction from this site [0].
(but before that, I had uninstalled nodejs which came from Ubuntu repository using "apt-get remove --purge nodejs" as root).

The way to install nodejs on Ubuntu as described on [0] is summarized as follows:

1. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
2. sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

After that, I installed grunt-init via: "npm install -g grunt-init." Then, I run "grunt-init" and it works!

[0] https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions